# Automatic note splitting - missed stems

Tags: scales, lilypond, modal

[image]Why are some stems missing?

```
\version "2.22.1"
\include "changePitch.ly"

nl = \break

chord_a = \relative c''' {<e gis c>}
chord_b = \relative c'' {<fis b d>}

root = {c d e f fis gis ais b}

motif_a = \relative {
\modalTranspose e e \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e d \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e c \root \chord_a 
\modalTranspose e b, \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e ais, \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e gis, \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e fis, \root \chord_a
\modalTranspose e f, \root \chord_a
}

motif_b = \relative {
\modalTranspose fis fis \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis gis \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis ais \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis b \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis c' \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis d' \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis e' \root \chord_b
\modalTranspose fis f' \root \chord_b
}
  
rhythm = { 
c8 c4
}


iaa = \new Staff
\new Voice
\with {
\remove "Note_heads_engraver"
\consists "Completion_heads_engraver"
\remove "Rest_engraver"
\consists "Completion_rest_engraver"
}

{

\key c \major
\time 2/4
\ottava1
\changePitch \rhythm \motif_a \nl \ottava0
\changePitch \rhythm \modalTranspose e e, \root \motif_a \nl
%\changePitch \rhythm \modalInversion e'' e'' \root \motif \nl
%\changePitch \rhythm \retrograde \modalInversion e'' e'' \root \motif \nl
  
}

iab = \new Staff
\with {
\remove "Note_heads_engraver"
\consists "Completion_heads_engraver"
\remove "Rest_engraver"
\consists "Completion_rest_engraver"
}
{
\ottava1
\changePitch \rhythm \motif_b \nl \ottava1
\changePitch \rhythm \modalTranspose fis fis' \root \motif_b \nl
}

\bookpart {

\header {

dedication  =  \markup { \with-dimensions #'(0 . 0) #'(0 . 0) \with-color #(rgb-color 1 0.99 0.94) \filled-box #'(-10000 . 10000) #'(-10000 . 10000) #0 }
title = \markup { \vspace #4 \fontsize #1 \override #'(font-name . "Consolas") \eyeglasses }

}

\score {
\new GrandStaff
<<
\iaa
\iab
>>

\layout {}

\midi{ \tempo 4 = 120 }

}

}

\paper {
indent = 0\mm
left-margin = #21
right-margin = #21
markup-system-spacing.basic-distance = #30
}
```

Comment: I found resolution! I'm sorry. 
`code
    \layout {
    \context {
    \Voice
    \remove "Note_heads_engraver"
    \consists "Completion_heads_engraver"
    \remove "Rest_engraver"
    \consists "Completion_rest_engraver"   
    }
    }
`

Comment: If you can remove the parts of the code that aren't required to demonstrate the problem, it will make it much easier to diagnose.

Comment: @semiono Yes, either that or `\new Staff \new Voice \with { ... }`. The problem here is that most engravers handling such stuff sit on Voice level, so when the heads are created on Staff level the engravers acknowledging heads won’t see them.

Answer (score 2):

You add a `Completion_heads_engraver` to the **Staff** in `\iab` instead of adding it to a **Voice** context.  This results in the completed `NoteHead` grobs getting produced at **Staff** level where they escape notice of the `Stem_engraver` that sits at **Voice** level and does not get to see grobs emitted at **Staff** level.

You just need to write things for `\iab` like you did for `\iaa`, namely adding an extra `\new Voice` before the `\with` clause substituting the normal notehead engravers.